# Preventing a particular thread to participating in thread scheduler when some threads doing their task

Tags: java, multithreading

I just want to run some threads as usual, I am not caring about how and when they switch between each other. But there is a last one thread remained that should not participate when other threads are running.
I have tried it by setting low priority to the last thread but it doesn't work and it switches between higher priority threads.

I got solution of it "a little bit", which is close to it by the below program but not exact what I want to do.

```
class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
static long value=0;
int no;
boolean flag;
public ThreadDemo(int no,boolean flag) {
    this.no=no;
    this.flag=flag;
}

public void run() {
    int i=0; 
    boolean tempf=true;
        while(tempf) {
        if(flag == true || value >= 30) {
            while(i<10) {
                try{sleep(100);} catch(Exception e) {}
                System.out.println("Thread # "+no+" is "+i);
                i++;
                value++;
            }
            tempf=false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And then call it in main class like this

```
    ThreadDemo th1 = new ThreadDemo(1,true);
    ThreadDemo th2 = new ThreadDemo(2,true);
    ThreadDemo th3 = new ThreadDemo(3,true);
    ThreadDemo th4 = new ThreadDemo(4,false);  

    th1.start();
    th2.start();
    th3.start();
    th4.start();
```

Here I want to execute run() method of th4 after completion of all three threads. But it actually invokes the run() method and also do switching between other threads.
Let me know if you want some clarification or info on it.

Comment: I think if you put th4.join() it should work.

Comment: There are many ways to have a thread run after other threads, depending on what you want to accomplish. The simplest is to start th1-th3, then `join()` all of them, and only then calling `th4.start()`.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
 ThreadDemo th1 = new ThreadDemo(1,true);
    ThreadDemo th2 = new ThreadDemo(2,true);
    ThreadDemo th3 = new ThreadDemo(3,true);
    ThreadDemo th4 = new ThreadDemo(4,true);  

    th1.start();
    th2.start();
    th3.start();
th1.join();
th2.join();
th3.join();
    th4.start();
```

Comment: It works, but I need more precise clarification on join(). Because it also work when I am using only one join with any th1..th3. what I'm seeing is, it pause the main thread whenever I call join() method by any thread, but in oracle tutorial site they told that. when we call join() with any thread like t.join(), causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates.but it does switch among 3 threads and I am also not seeing any diff between calling one join() or more than one join. Please clarify this precisely on the join().

Comment: there is no warranty about the finish/start line of a thread, so this is possible that one of the thread takes 10 seconds to does its work, so you need to join for all threads you want to finish. here the first three threads after printing something sleep for 100 ms, so this is 99% possible all of them terminated with a very small time(1ns), but we are not programming with possibilities, we program with logic, please read [this article](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) it may help you dude.

Comment: your answer and comment both really helped me to get my solution. But I am seeing different nature of join() when I am using it inside the thread process( like in the run() of thread) it doesn't take the control for the whole process. it does switching between threads.

Comment: no it's not for bypassing or switching. consider the `gui` thread is showing "Loading..." until the data gets prepared by `data` thread, here the gui needs to wait until data thread gets finished(terminated), so it(gui) `join()` for data thread, it means JVM will signal the joined thread(gui) whenever thread data gets terminated.

Comment: I think, in Gui and data thread situation, Gui thread will not be waiting for the data thread to be finished. Because what I said already it does switching between threads even when join() has been used. sorry for stretching this topic too much.